# Check Cron job ran in last 10 minutes

Tags: unix, cron

I have multiple scripts running in cron and my cron log is  very flooded .
I just need to write a unix command to check if one particular scheduled script ran in last 10 minutes .

Comment: You're grepping through the log file, right?  Not manually reading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "touch" some file from script and check atime of this file.
Something like "touch -a /var/run/app.state" from cron script.
And for check you can use stat command with custom format to extract access time of file and calculate difference between now and this time.